# runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
    int maxProfit(vector<int>& prices)
    {
        int smallest = prices[0];
        int profit=0;


        for(int i=1;i<prices.size();i++)
        {
            int diff=0;
           if(prices[i]>smallest)    
               diff = prices[i]-smallest;
           else
               smallest = prices[i];
          if(diff > profit)
              profit=diff;
        }
        return profit;
    }};
```

> Question) Say you have an array for which the ith element is the price
>   of a given stock on day i.
>
> If you were only permitted to complete at most one transaction (i.e.,
>   buy one and sell one share of the stock), design an algorithm to find
>   the maximum profit.
>
> Note that you cannot sell a stock before you buy one.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: [7,1,5,3,6,4] Output: 5 Explanation: Buy on day 2 (price = 1)
>   and sell on day 5 (price = 6), profit = 6-1 = 5.
>                Not 7-1 = 6, as selling price needs to be larger than buying price.
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: [7,6,4,3,1] Output: 0 Explanation: In this case, no transaction
>   is done, i.e. max profit = 0.

I am getting the error:

```
reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' (stl_vector.h)
```

Comment: "stl_vector.h"?  Q: What compiler/compiler version are you using?  Q: Any chance you could write a short [MCVE]?

Comment: Thank You for replying. It's a leetcode problem. https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock/

Comment: The thing that matters is this error message: `reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' (stl_vector.h)`.  It would be helpful to know a) your C++ compiler and version, and b) how you're initializing "prices".  Q: Is there a "prices[0]"?  A "prices[1]"?  A valid "prices[i]" whenever you reference it?  A small, self-contained program (an [MCVE]) would help answer this.

Comment: Hi paulsm4, I was able to figure it out. So, one of the test cases had empty vector as input.Hence , it threw the error when I tried to access prices[0] in the first line. So, i added a check-> if(prices.empty()) return 0; and the answer turned out to be correct. Thank You!:)

Answer (score 0):

So, one of the test cases had empty vector as input.Hence , it threw the error when I tried to access prices[0] in the first line. So, i added a check-> if(prices.empty()) return 0; and the answer turned out to be correct.